# How to add a UIView on 2 ViewControllers Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

TLDR; How do I get the same UIView to be on 2 different ViewControllers?
Using Objective-C

I am making a small settings type option for an app.

There is a button which when pressed gives a popup(UIView) which gives access to some UISwitches to control some settings and then an "OK" button on the UIView to close it. I control the popup by making the alpha 1 when popping up and 0 when hiding.

I need that UIView to be available on 2 different ViewControllers. And the UISwitch state needs to be in sync for the 2 ViewControllers

Thanks!

Comment: Make a copy or pass it to the other controller in the initializer and add it in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Search create customerview with xib in google

Answer (score 0):

You can create XIb and load it on different View controllers

I can help you in Swift.

Step 1 - Create an XIB and assign a UIView to it.

Step 2 - Call that View in your respective view controllers as below

```
    var sampleoneView: SampleView?

    var sampleTwoView: SampleView?
```

Initialise these views as below

```
    sampleoneView = SampleView.initSampleView(X vX:CGFloat, Y vY:CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)
    sampleTwoView = SampleView.initSampleView(X vX:CGFloat, Y vY:CGFloat, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)
```

where the initSampleView func will be defined as below

```
    public class func initSampleView() -> SampleView{
    let sampleView:SampleView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("SampleView", owner: self, options: nil)?.last as! SampleView
    sampleView.frame = CGRect(x: vX, y: vY, width: width, height: height)
    return sampleView
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> There is a button which when pressed gives a popup(UIView) which gives access to some UISwitches to control some settings and then an "OK" button on the UIView to close it. I control the popup by making the alpha 1 when popping up and 0 when hiding.

So this is not just a view and its subviews but a whole set of controller behaviors that operate upon them. Thus this needs to be a child view controller instantiated with its view twice. Use a Container View in the storyboard in both places, with the Embed segues leading to same view controller and its view.

> And the UISwitch state needs to be in sync for the 2 ViewControllers

Write all needed info into UserDefaults as the user makes changes in the view, and read and obey it when the view controller appears.